# Add a property to a Button or other type of Objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I always created additional property to MovieCLips using the syntax

```
myMC.myProperty
```

without any sort of declaration... But i can use this method only with MovieClips.. What about if i want to add a property to a button or any different type of object? I need to extend the class? Do you can me suggest how? Many thanks

Comment: As @Timofei says, you should extend or use dynamic classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add property to movieclips in runtime because `MovieClip` is `dynamic` class. If the class is not dynamic, you should extend it to create methods and properties.
[Read about dynamic classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_10.html).

Comment: child class should be dynamic to achive dynamic property addition.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to create custom classes for nearly everything.
I would extend the relevant class and set up a `private var` for your new property. You can then pass in the value to the constructor or add a getter/setter method to call externally.

```
    private function _myProperty:int;

    public function get myProperty():int
    {
        return _myProperty;
    }

    public function set myProperty(newVal:int):void
    {
        _myProperty = newVal;
    }
```

Getter/setter methods add a few lines of code that may seem unnecessary but on big projects when you find a property is being set and you don't know why, you can put a break point in your `set myProperty`

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass is main solution.
2. Next works only with mx components (flex sdk 3).
   Most components have *data : Object* property that you can freely use to store data.
3. [Monkey patching](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryAhC1vw8Os) sometimes is the only way to go. It allows you to add custom properties to flex sdk classes. I don't think you should use it in your case. But I used it to change core logic that is locked by *private* keyword in flex sdk.

Hope that helps.